Why don't zoom lenses provide higher aperture for lower focal lengths?
I have a Nikon lense with below specification:
Focal Length Range: 18-140mm
Maximum Aperture Range: f/3.5-5.6
So the diameter of the lense is at least: 140/5.6 = 25mm.
My question is if the lense has a diameter of at least 25mm, then why can't it have a f/1 or f/1.4 or f/2 or even f/2.8 where the maximum diameter required is 18mm only (in case of f/1). What is stopping Nikon from providing higher aperture from lower focal lengths ?
The lense: AF-S DX NIKKOR 18-140MM F/3.5-5.6G ED VR

Because it is too hard to design a retrofocus UWA lens that is also sharp when using light from large angles (wide apertures). Because of design limitations you end up with a lot of optical aberrations when you try (soft focus, chromatic aberrations, coma, etc).
Also note that what matters is the size of the entrance pupil, which isn't really the objective element. It is the apparent size of the aperture restriction as viewed from the objective end, and as magnified by the optics at that end. If you look you will see that with a retrofocus design the entrance pupil is smaller than the objective element.
As the various lens elements move within a zoom lens it can change the magnification of the aperture restriction (constant f# zoom), or it can keep the magnification constant (variable f#). Or it can do something in between (smaller range variable), which is what your lens is doing.

Thanks for your answer. If you dont mind could you please explain it further in simple terms ? I did not really understand. Pardon my lack of knowledge.

@SauravMajumder, the restriction to light (f#) is not the physical size of the aperture opening, nor is it the physical size of the objective element. It is the apparent size of the aperture opening as magnified by the objective element. I.e. when you look into the objective end of a lens you are not seeing the physical aperture blades/opening; you are seeing an image of it projected and magnified (+/-) by the objective elements. And that is the same thing (restriction) the light entering the lens sees.

As you know, the size of the image changes as you zoom. The size of the image of an object is 7.8 times larger at focal length 140mm than it is at 18mm. Now the image generated by the lens is a projected image cast by the lens. As the image enlarges with the zoom, it also dims.  This dimming is quite severe. Each time the focal length doubles, the image size of objects also doubles. An image size change or 2X magnification induces a 4X reduction in image brilliance. Unless we somehow compensate for this light loss, severe under exposure will result.
Lens makers have a trick up their sleeve that relieves this potential under exposure. By the way, the exact opposite happens if you are zooming out (image getting smaller). Their cure is to construct the front lens element group is such a way that apparent diameter of the aperture (iris diaphragm) appears change with the zoom. In other words, the aperture diameter appears to contract or expand with the zoom. On an expensive zoom, this action will likely completely compensate and create a constant aperture zoom lens. Your lens is not a constant aperture lens, it fails and shifts f/3.5 to f/5.6 as you near its maximum magnification.
Since your lens is not the top-of-the-line zoom, your max light gathering f-number is a modest f/3.5.
Should the lens maker choose to make this lens an f/2 or f/1.4, the lens diameter must be enlarged significantly. Keep in mind that such a lens is slender at the edges with a bulge at the center. Light rays entering at the edge of the lens must be refracted inward significantly, such a lens will have severe aberrations unless well corrected. Now you are talking big money to manufacture. Likely this lens would be beyond your means.

How do you figure such a lens would be beyond OP's means in particular? Do you have some way of knowing about their financial status, and is it relevant to speculate on that at all?

@ilkkachu Because even those with very large corporate budgets know that using several different lenses across several different focal length ranges give better image quality and costs significantly less. Compare a set of premium f/2.8 constant aperture lenses from 24mm to 1600mm (using an 800mm + 2X TC) for FF at around $20K-30K total to something like the Canon DigiSuper 100AF at around $200K (with 9.3-930mm FL for a 3.9X crop factor sensor that gives an FF equivalent AoV of 36-3600mm).

A tip of the hat to Michael C from Alan Marcus

Because the aperture used to calculate f-number is measured as it appears from outside the front of the lens. This is what is more properly called the entrance pupil. When you zoom, the amount of magnification between the front of the lens and the physical aperture diaphragm changes. So even though the actual physical size of the aperture diaphragm is the same, it appears to be smaller from the front of the lens when it is zoomed out to 18mm than when it is zoomed in to 140mm.
For lenses that do all of the variable magnification between the physical diaphragm and the front of the lens, the size of the entrance pupil increases at the same rate as the magnification, and the lens is called a constant aperture lens. A 70-200mmf/2.8 lens is a constant aperture lens. So is a 24-70mm f/2.8 lens. Your lens does a significant amount of the magnification between the front element and the aperture diaphragm. Otherwise that 5.1463mm entrance pupil would only be f/27.2! But the entrance pupil is magnified by a factor of 4.86X while the focal length is increased by a factor of 7.7778X. So your lens does roughly 63% of the additional magnification in front of the aperture diaphragm and the other 37% behind it when you zoom from 18mm to 140mm.
Related questions here at Photography SE:
Why are large zoom ratio constant apertures lenses not generally available?
How do constant aperture zoom lenses work?
How do zoom lenses restrict their widest aperture at the telephoto end?
About those all in one lenses and why they are such compromises.
If you really want to go there, you can get a broadcast quality video lens such as the Canon DigiSuper 100AF that projects an image circle large enough for a 2/3" broadcast camera with a 9.3-930mm focal length. It gives an equivalent field of view on such cameras as that of a 36-3656mm lens on a FF camera. It only weighs 60 pounds and costs a bit more than $200,000 (way back in 2013 dollars). And that is for a 9.59x5.39mm video sensor with a 3.9X crop factor.

For a Full Frame sensor it would need the front element to be 4X as wide, 4X as tall, and be 4X as long. It'd probably weigh about 64X as much (Each lens element would have 64X the volume when 4X larger in the three linear dimensions), and maybe 4,096X as much (i.e. $819 Million USD). If you're asking for the Defense Department of a major industrial power, they might be willing to make one for you?
